# Is it possible to do dead letter queue using Redis?

Tags: python, redis, celery

Is it possible to do `dead letter queue` using `Celery` and `Redis`?

I found some examples using `RabbitMQ`, and I saw that `RabbitMQ` supports `Dead Letter Queue`, like this https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html.

My question is: Does Redis support `Dead Letter Queue`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to implement a dead letter queue using Redis, specifically by utilizing Redis Streams. Redis Streams allow for a more robust solution, including features such as claiming and the delivery counter.

For more details, please refer to the official Redis documentation on Streams: [Redis Streams Tutorial - Claiming and the Delivery Counter.](https://redis.io/docs/data-types/streams-tutorial/#claiming-and-the-delivery-counter)